# Is it considered a bad practice to use the Route object to get route parameters from inside a controller method? [Laravel]

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have multiple routes that resolve to a single controller method. I'm using `Route` to get the route parameters since Laravel passes the parameters to the method in the order they're defined. Although the `Route` approach works, it increases the complexity of our unit tests. Any suggestions?

```
<?php

// routes/api.php

$router->get('/test/{another_example_param}', ['uses' => 'ExampleController@show']);
$router->get('/test/{example_param}/thing/{another_example_param}', ['uses' => 'ExampleController@show']);
$router->get('/testing/{example_param}', ['uses' => 'ExampleController@show']);
```

```
<?php

// ExampleController.php

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;

class ExampleController extends Controller {
  // Explicitly defining route parameters
  public function show(string $example_param, string $another_example_param) {
    echo "example param: $example_param";
    echo "another_example param: $another_example_param";
  }  

  // Extracting route params from Route approach
  public function showAlternate(Route $route) {
    $example_param = $route->example_param;
    $another_example_param = $route->another_example_param;

    echo "example param: $example_param";
    echo "another_example param: $another_example_param";    
  }  
}
```

Comment: since this is a fairly open question, can you show how it complicates your unit tests?

Comment: Have you checked this? 
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters